# Postgres PgAgent job status not running

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

The job status keeps showing as F in the Statistics -> Status
I did run the code of the job in the query area and it works but I don't know why it's failing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ors5W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it was showing as F
go to services in task manager and find the service "pgagent-pg14" and its status was STOPPED and running that would fail every time (can check in the windows event manager).
Uninstall everything and deleting every possible folder of Postgres and then cleaning out the registry will give you a better chance of it working in the next installation.